# doPost not returning response servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Hi I am testing servlets and was able to successfully run the GET request and have encountered an issue with POST request. Am triggering URL calls using Postman app.

Below is my code for the servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.GenericServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        String user = request.getParameter("user");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<B>The user is: ");
        pw.println(user);
        pw.close();
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {

        String user = req.getParameter("user");
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
        pw.println("<B>The user is: ");
        pw.println(user);
        pw.close();
    }

}
```

The GET request is working fine but when am triggering the POST request and passing a "user" parameter in the request, am getting the response - The user is null.

Comment: You have exactly the same code in both handler methods. This should be working. It is more likely that your POST call doesn't contain the parameter "user". How extactly do you call the POST request?

Comment: I tested your servlet code using Chrome Postman. The POST call seems to be working. FYI- I set the Content-Type field in the header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and I passed the user field in the Body (not as a URL parameter). As vanje pointed out, it would help to know how you're sending the request.